# Programmatically create attribute of type select and options

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, programmatically, select

I am having following category structure.

```
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
    - Category 3.1
        - Category 3.1.1
        - Category 3.1.2
        - Category 3.1.3
        - Category 3.1.4
        - Category 3.1.5
    - Category 3.2
        - Category 3.2.1
        - Category 3.2.2
        - Category 3.2.3
        - Category 3.2.4
        - Category 3.2.5
    - Category 3.3
        - Category 3.3.1
        - Category 3.3.2
        - Category 3.3.3
        - Category 3.3.4
        - Category 3.3.5
Category 4
```

In my layered navigation I need this as follows:

```
Category 3.1 (attribute)
    - Category 3.1.1 (options)
    - Category 3.1.2 (options)
    - Category 3.1.3 (options)
    - Category 3.1.4 (options)
    - Category 3.1.5 (options)

Category 3.2 (attribute)
    - Category 3.2.1 (options)
    - Category 3.2.2 (options)
    - Category 3.2.3 (options)
    - Category 3.2.4 (options)
    - Category 3.2.5 (options)
```

I need to make this dynamically and programmatically.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: i had tried creating the attribute programmatically and adding options to it.but latter in the mid i found that this are the product attributues.i wanted the attribute at the category level.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a Layered Navigation then all you need to do is make the category an Anchor by setting `is Anchor` to "Yes" in the category page then make sure that the Attributes for your product are able to be used in a Layered Navigation.

Comment: i know this.i am looking for the category name to act as the attribute.